# How do I determine the Wronskian $y_1$ and $y_2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

[image]

[image]

So this is an answer but reading and reading. I still have no idea how to determine the Wronskian y1 and y2. And when do I use it?
I mean in general how do i find y1 and y2?
I know the answer for this but I am asking in general if another question requires me to use Wronskian.

Comment: The wronskian is a determinant so $W=\cos^2 t+\sin^2 t=1$

Comment: Thats not really my question. 
I am finding out how to determine what y1 and y2 to use.
For different questions, and when to use it.

Comment: These are solutions to the homogeneous differential equation

Answer (score 1):

$W$ is the Wronskain it's a determinant.
$$W (y_1,y_2)=y'_1y_2-y_1y'_2$$
$$W(\sin t, \cos t)=\cos t \cos t  -\sin t  (-\sin t )  \\ W=\cos^2 t+\sin^2 t=1 \ne 0$$
$y_1,y_2$ here are solutions to the homogeneous differential equation:
$$y''+y=0$$
$$r^2+1=0 \implies r=\pm i$$
$$y=c_1y_1+c_2y_2=c_1 \cos t+c_2\sin t$$

Answer (score 0):

If $y_1$ and $y_2$ are the solution to a homogeneous differential equation the Wronskian is given by:

$$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    y_1 & y_2 \\
    y_1' & y_2' \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$

In case of $y''+y= 0$ the characteristic equation is $r^2+1=0$ which implies roots are $r=\pm i$ which means the solution is $c_1 \cos t+ c_2 \sin t$. So $y_1 =\cos t$ and $y_2= \sin t$ and so the Wronskian is

$$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    \cos t & \sin t \\
    -\sin t & \cos t \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$

Which evaluates $\cos^2t+\sin^2t=1$ which means the Wronskian is non zero and hence the solution are independent.